# Closure access to private constructor in C#

Tags: c#, closures

I understand how in C# closures allow access to private variables declared in the same scope as an anonymous method, so that those variables are available when the method is invoked in a different scope.

But what about private constructors? This code works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someClassFactory = SomeClass.GetFactoryMethod();

        var someclass = someClassFactory();
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    private SomeClass()
    {
    }

    public static Func<SomeClass> GetFactoryMethod()
    {
        return () => new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

As the compiler creates a class for the closure, how does it then reference the private constructor, or otherwise allow it to be accessed when the anonymous method is invoked by the client code?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with closure. It just a method call.

Comment: @CriketerOnSO The question is about how the closure is translated into a method call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the compiler doesn't need to create a class at all - it can just create a static method:

```
public static Func<SomeClass> GetFactoryMethod()
{
    return __GeneratedMethod;
}

private static SomeClass __GeneratedMethod()
{
    return new SomeClass();
}
```

Even when it *does* need to generate a class - e.g. if `GetFactoryMethod()` had a parameter which was captured by the lambda expression - it would generate a *nested* class, and nested classes have access to the private members of their enclosing classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Foo() {}

    public class Bar
    {
        public Foo MakeNewFoo()
        {
            return new Foo(); // This is absolutely fine
        }
    }
}
```